# TypeError: pretty_print() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python

PyCharm return "TypeError: pretty_print() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given"
I've searched for the whole night but still can't figure it out

```
from IPython.display import display
from sympy import *
from sympy.interactive import printing 
printing.init_printing
t = symbols('t')
a=5
b=3
pprint(integrate(1+a/b+(a/b-1)*sinh(a*t)*sin(b*t)-(a/b+1)*cosh(a*t)*cos(b*t)+sinh(a*t)*cos(b*t)-a/b*cosh(a*t)*sin(b*t)), (t, 0, t))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `(t, 0, t)` is the *second* argument to `pprint` (which takes only *one* positional argument), but it's meant to be the second argument for `integrate`.

BTW, an integral from 0 to `t` `dt` seems strange as it uses the same variable for both integration and the upper bound.

---

You can write this in a cleaner way:

```
printing.init_printing() # CALL this function

t, x = symbols('t x')
a=5
b=3

# Nice readable formula for the function we're integrating
func = (
    1 + a/b + (a/b - 1) * sinh(a*t) * sin(b*t)
    - (a/b + 1) * cosh(a*t) * cos(b*t)
    + sinh(a*t) * cos(b*t)
    - a/b * cosh(a*t) * sin(b*t)
)

# Integrate `func` from 0 to some `x`
the_integral = integrate(func, (t, 0, x))

# Output the result
pprint(the_integral)
```

Note how putting the formula for the function in a separate variable `func` and the integration result into `the_integral` makes it harder to get lost in parentheses and pass `(t, 0, t)` as the argument to `pprint` instead of `integrate`.